# Pulling and pushing in github

Tags: github

So here's the scenario. I am currently making changes to a file. Without my knowing my colleague is also making some changes at the same time as I was doing mine and just pushed his changes to the master. If I'm going to commit my changes locally and then pull his changes from the master before pushing it back to the master, would my changes be lost?

Thanks.

Comment: Before you push anything to a shared repository, you should do a pull first to see if any changes have been made to things you've changed. `git` should tell you that you have merges to do.

Comment: The scenario you describe is extremely common, and Git knows to watch for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your changes would not be lost. Git would realise that you have both made changes to the same file and would prompt you to merge the changes when you try and pull his changes into your local repository.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I was thinking about that but wasn't 100% sure.